# Why am I getting a compiler error trying to include a call to UserServiceBaseLifetime() in my Asp.NetCore application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to work through a sample for ".NET Core Workers as Windows Services".
The link is here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/

I have included the **Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting** NuGet package.
I'm running into a compile issue trying to add **.UseServiceBaseLifetime(**).

Here is the code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceBaseLifetime()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler error:

> Error CS1061  'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'UseServiceBaseLifetime' and no accessible extension method
> 'UseServiceBaseLifetime' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)  WorkerService1

I believe that the sample is based on .Net Core 3.0 preview.

Am I missing a NuGet package, including a reference?

Has the method named changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UseServiceBaseLifetime` was renamed to `UseWindowsService` before GA of 3.0. The extension method lives in [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/).

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1288) for reference.